# How to make these 3 tables communicate with each other on Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

On the sheet with the link below, I need to do this:

In the case x exists on A and C rows, not on B row > total grade (on table 3) of x should be calculated as 10 (A+B from table 2)
And same for y and z.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QW9Ansn0n4NgTkLFnKjr64xEK2JCR-6KTZWe-LKAqBc/edit#gid=0

I couldn't find a way to do this with sumif or hlookup etc.

Could you please help me solve this? It's very crucial task for my team.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, Please show the desired result? I am not sure what you mean in description.

Comment: I showed the expected final result on Table 3 in spreadsheet actually. if x exist on row A on table 1, add A value which is on table 2 (as grade) to x value on table 3 (as total grade). If x exists on B row repeat the previous task.

Answer (score 2):

I added this formula to cell B15 of the sheet and copied it down:

`=SUM(ArrayFormula(IF($B$3:$C$5=$A15;vlookup($A$3:$A$5;$A$9:$B$11;2;0))))`

Comment: Wow, that's exactly what I need! It seems that it will be enough for me, but I'll try to apply this to whole document today, and see if it works. Thanks a lot!